# Как сохранить текст из input без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Как передать значение в текстовый фаил, без перезагрузки, что бы значение в файле не перезаписывалось, следующее новое значение падало на новую строку или рядом.

```
<form method="post" action="form.php" class="form2">
 <input type='text' placeholder='ФИО' name='textblock'>
 <input class='button' type='submit' value='Отправить'>
</form>
```

Comment: через angularjs  input нужно присвоить модель а потом постом отправить ее на сервер, там сохранить данные например в файл, ну или сразу сохранить в localstorage

Comment: Serge Esmanovich, причем тут angular и localstorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Форма HTML

```
<form method="post" action="form.php" class="form2">
    <input type='text' placeholder='ФИО' name='textblock' autofocus>
    <input class='button' type='submit' value='Отправить'>
</form>
```

Выполняем AJAX запрос через jQuery при отправке формы:

```
$(function() {
    $('.form2').submit(function() {
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).find('input').serialize(), function() {
            $('.form2 input[type="text"]').val('').focus(); // опционально
            alert('Successfully saved');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

PHP (form.php)

```
<?php
if ( ! empty($_POST['textblock'])) {
    file_put_contents('data.txt', $_POST['textblock']."\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: По какой причине слив? Выполнено исходя из вопроса и меток php, jquery, ajax.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, понятно.  Почему слили хз, у кого то критические дни, или череп жмет от изобилия знания и на этой почве проще было слить, да и бог с ним.